Let $a,b,c$ be three nonzero natural numbers for which the equation $x^2-(a^2+b^2+4c^2+1)x+ab+2ac+2bc=0$ admits **an** integer root.
The problem
Let $a,b,c$ be three nonzero natural numbers for which the equation $x^2-(a^2+b^2+4c^2+1)x+ab+2ac+2bc=0$ admits an integer root. Determine the solutions of the equation.
The idea
I tried using the quadric formula but just got lost in a bunch of long numbers, trying to make them look like some squares...Other than using the quadric formula that suggests that there can be 2 real solutions and proving that one of them is irrational, I don't have any other idea.
Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

If you let $d=2c,$ then at least the coefficients become symmetric. Not sure if that helps.

Your idea is wrong since a,b,c are natural numbers $a^2+b^2+4c^2+1$ will also be a natural number so since the sum of the two roots is an integer and one the roots is an integer then both must be integers

"an integer root"? This can affect the answer highly. One integer root along with any other real root? Or only a single root?

Okay as a,b,c are natural the other root is bound to be an integer

@Gwen It can be as many roots you want, but only one of them to be integer

If there are two distinct roots that they are either both rational or both irrational.  If you are certain that claiming there is exactly one integer is relevant (i'd personally assume that was just language) then the roots are $\frac {M \pm \sqrt{K}}2$.  If one is an integer than the other is two.  SO if there is only one then the expression is a perfect square and $(a^2 + b^2 +4c^2+1)^2 - 4(ab+2ac + 2bc)= 0$.

I really do not think the question is claiming there is exactly one and only one root.  I think it just means there is one and there might be more.  For example  "Where can I buy a quart of milk"  "The grocery store has a quart of milk."  "Really?  Only one?!  What happens if two people want milk?"

@fleablood sadly it seems like ionela here do not drink milk....

Its given that $a,b,c$ are natural numbers$(\gt 0)$ which means that they are also integers $\implies a^2+b^2+(2c)^2+1$ is also a natural number or integer $\\ \implies$ sum of roots of the equation is an integer. It is given that one of the roots is an integer and since their sum is an integer they both must be integers.
The question states that one of the roots is an integer but never limits us to only one integer root other root can be anything
For starters lets define a function $f(x)$ and observe its behaviour.
Let, $$f(x)=x^2-(a^2+b^2+4c^2+1)+ab+2bc+2ac $$
$$f(0)=ab+2bc+2ac \quad[\because a,b,c\gt0\implies ab+2bc+2ac\gt0]\implies f(0)\gt0\\$$
$$f(1)=-(a^2+b^2+4c^2-ab-2bc-2ac)=\frac{-1}2[\left(a^2+b^2-2ab)+(a^2+(2c)^2-2(2c)a)+(b^2+(2c)^2-2(2c)b)\right]=\frac{-1}2\left[(a-b)^2+(a-2c)^2+(b-2c)^2\right]\le0\implies f(1)\le0$$
If $f(1)\lt0 \implies$ one of the roots of $f(x)=0$ is $x=\alpha\in(0,1) \implies \alpha\ne$ integer. So we can say that $f(1)\not\lt0$
Then only one condition is left that $f(1)=0$ so $x=1$(an integer) is a root of $f(x)=0$.
$\implies \frac{-1}2[(a-b)^2+(a-2c)^2+(b-2c)^2]=0\implies a=b=2c$(let$=k$ also an integer)
Let $\beta$ be another root of the equation.
sum of roots $= (a^2+b^2+4c^2+1)=1+\beta\implies\beta=3k^2$(also an integer)
ANSWER:
The roots of the equation are $x=1,3k^2$ where $k=a=b=2c$.

Thank you for your answer! I have 2 questions: 1) The problem specifies that there should be only one root integer, and you found 2... 2) How do you know that $f(1)<f(x)<f(0)$, if $x\in(0,1)$, because we don't know if $f(x)$ is a linear function

@ionelabuciu as for the answer of your 1st question from the given conditions of the questions i already proved why both the roots must be integer read the initial lines of the answer

Yes, i understand, but the problem asks for only one ineteger

@ionelabuciu about the 2nd question the given function is a parabola so we know that it is a continuous function so if in going from x=0 to x=1 f(x) changes sign then f(x) must have taken value 0 at some point in between 0 and 1. This is what we call intermediate value theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem). It states that if f(x) is a continuous function then f(x) will take all the values from f(a) to f(b) for some c in (a,b)

@Ionelabuciu the problem never restricted us to have only one integer root. no information is given about the other root, but we can gain some information about those roots from the given data. It does not say only one. You are misunderstanding the line

I'm going to use $c=2c$ for making writing easier
Let the two roots be $\alpha,\beta$
Note that the roots are positive since the  sum and product of roots is positive
We have $$
(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\ge0
$$
The equality holding only when $a=b=c$
Expanding the inequality we get
$$
\begin{align}
&a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca \\ &\Rightarrow\alpha+\beta-1\ge\alpha\beta\\ &\Rightarrow (\alpha-1)(\beta-1)\le0
\end{align}
$$
The less than zero condition can never hold since that would imply either one of the terms is negative or that there exists a positive integer less than 1 hence only the equality can hold
So we get $a=b=c$ and either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is 1 since the choice of root is arbitrary we can take $\alpha=1$ and since we know the product of roots the other root must be $3a^2$
Note: the inequality used is just Cauchy Shwarz

Thanks for your answer. But the problem specifies that there should be only one root integer, and you found 2...correct me if I'm wrong

@IONELABUCIU see, if one root is an Integer, and the sum of it with the other root is an integer as well, then the other root must be an integer

@Gwen Oooo...ok... one more question: How did you replace $a,b,c$ with $\alpha, \beta$?

I didn't replace. By Vieta's formula, $a^2+b^2+4c^2+1=\alpha+\beta$. If $\alpha,a,b,c$ all are integers, then $\beta$ must be a integer right? @IONELABUCIU

@IONELABUCIU an integral root just means there is an integral root not there is only one integral root
